# Batch Script - Parameter Nested Inside Variable?

Tags: variables, batch-file, parameters

Here's the scenario:

I have a parent script that calls about a dozen child scripts, one of which is a somewhat complex folder/file syncing operation. Each of the child scripts writes a variable to a batch file (e.g. variable.bat), which is then loaded by the parent script at next execution.

The folder syncing script chooses from a large list of folders based upon a parameter passed to it via the parent script.

The child script's SET command looks something like this:

```
ECHO SET pair-folder-%1=yes>>c:\variable.bat
```

This produces a variable at next run that is loaded by the parent script. Herein lies the rub: How do I script an action (via IF trap) that calls that variable the next time the child script comes around? I imagine my IF trap would look something like this:

```
IF %pair-folder-%1%=yes GOTO nopair
```

The problem is I can't seem to get the batch to interpret that correctly - I have tried nesting the variable a few different ways, using Delayed Expansion, etc. Is it necessary to map the parameter to a local variable first?

Basically, once the parent scripts calls variable.bat at next execution, how do I then reference that newly set variable from within the child script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are appending `set pair-folder-%1=yes` lines to `variable.bat` then you'll get `varable.bat` to establish an increasing set of `pair-folder-*` variables.

Now if you want to check whether `pair-folder-%` is set, then

```
if defined pair-folder-%1 ...
```

will do that for you.

If you want to find the value of pair-folder-%1 (ie it's not just set or not set) then

```
set "valuefound="
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i in ( 'set pair-folder-%1 2^>nul' ) do (
 if /i "%%i"=="pair-folder-%1" set "valuefound=%%j"
)
```

should do that - `valuefound` would be "set" to no value (ie undefined) if the variable is undefined else its value.

Comment: THANK YOU!

IF DEFINED totally takes the cake - I had to map the parameter to a variable before it was recognized properly, but that's only one extra (temporary) line. Excellent suggestion, thanks again.